# Animations wont run

Tags: css, sass, haml, css-animations

I'm trying to run some animations in scss and I'm running into difficulty. In chrome dev tools it shows my element has the correct animation set and I've even copy pasted the keyframes rule into codepen and tried it there and it worked, yet when I run it in my website it doesn't work. I've been stuck with this for hours.

Here is a fiddle demonstraiting: http://jsfiddle.net/58xrZ/1/

This was written in Scss and HAML and is as follows

```
ul.tab-selection {
      width: 38.338926174%;
      float: right;
      position: relative;
      min-height: 20em;

      li {
        text-align: center;
        height: 6em;
        width: 6em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;

        &:first-child {
          background : radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle farthest-corner, rgba(98, 78, 44, 1) 0%, rgba(98, 78, 44, 0.66) 85.3%, rgba(98, 78, 44, 0.6) 100%);
          background : -moz-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle farthest-corner, rgba(98, 78, 44, 1) 0%, rgba(98, 78, 44, 0.66) 85.3%, rgba(98, 78, 44, 0.6) 100%);
          background : -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle farthest-corner, rgba(98, 78, 44, 1) 0%, rgba(98, 78, 44, 0.66) 85.3%, rgba(98, 78, 44, 0.6) 100%);
          top: 0;
          right: 50%;
          margin-right: -50px;      
          animation-name: first;
          animation-duration: 3s;
          -webkit-animation-name: first;
          -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
          a {
            width: 4em;
            padding: 2em 1em
          }
        }

        &:not(:first-child){
          bottom: 1.5em;
        }


        &:nth-child(2) {
          background: radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle farthest-corner, rgba(121, 85, 48, 1) 0%, rgba(121, 85, 48, 0.66) 85.3%, rgba(121, 85, 48, 0.6) 100%);
          background: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle farthest-corner, rgba(121, 85, 48, 1) 0%, rgba(121, 85, 48, 0.66) 85.3%, rgba(121, 85, 48, 0.6) 100%);
          background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle farthest-corner, rgba(121, 85, 48, 1) 0%, rgba(121, 85, 48, 0.66) 85.3%, rgba(121, 85, 48, 0.6) 100%);
          filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Stlye=2);
        }

        &:last-child {
          background : radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle farthest-corner, rgba(111, 68, 44, 1) 0%, rgba(111, 68, 44, 0.66) 85.3%, rgba(111, 68, 44, 0.6) 100%);
          background : -moz-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle farthest-corner, rgba(111, 68, 44, 1) 0%, rgba(111, 68, 44, 0.66) 85.3%, rgba(111, 68, 44, 0.6) 100%);
          background : -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle farthest-corner, rgba(111, 68, 44, 1) 0%, rgba(111, 68, 44, 0.66) 85.3%, rgba(111, 68, 44, 0.6) 100%);
          filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Stlye=2);
          right: 0;
          a {
            left: 3px;
            padding: 2em 1em;
          }
        }

        a {
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          font-family: 'Lora', serif;
          color: #AE843D;
          text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
          padding: 1.5em 1em;

          &:hover {
            color: #3D6F51;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

and in Haml

```
%ul.tab-selection
  %li.active.current-projects
    %a{ :href => '#current-projects', 'data-toggle' => 'tab' }
      Current
      %br Projects
  %li.secret
    %a{ :href => '#secret', 'data-toggle' => 'tab' }
      The
      %br
      Secret Shop
  %li.favorite
    %a{ :href => '#favorite', 'data-toggle' => 'tab' }
      Favorite
      %br Links
```

Comment: Try placing the browser prefixed properties before the unprefixed ones

Comment: Nope still not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the keyframes at the bottom of your CSS. You also need to have browser prefixed versions of the `@keyframes` animation(s) so that when you say `-webkit-animation:...` for example it will actually go to the `@-webkit-keyframes`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/58xrZ/2/)

It likely only worked in CodePen because it was using a prefixer, which automatically adds prefixes

Comment: It was the webkit, I usually use CodePen to because of that factor, I dislike remembering which prefixes for what heh.